# Address the last or first element in a wrapped flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
#content {
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  padding: 40px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.name-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.name-container.four {
  font-size: 38px;
}

div.name-container div:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="XXX" />
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div class="name-container"> <div>Prename <strong>Name</strong></div> <div>Prename <strong>Name</strong></div> <div>Prename <strong>Name</strong></div> <div>Prename <strong>Name</strong></div> <div>Prename <strong>Name</strong></div> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It applies a border on the right side of each element except for the last one. I want to remove the border on the right side if the subsequent element wraps and appears on the next line. Is this achievable?

I can't change the DOM so I really need to know if it is possible to address the last or first element of the wrapped flexbox.

Furthermore the content in #content is dynamic and placed via a script. So the actual length of the container varies.

Is there something easier than this:

```js
// Get all elements within the flex container
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#content .name-container div');

let previousTop = null;
let lastUnwrappedIndices = [];

// Determine the indices of the last elements that haven't wrapped in each row
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const rect = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
  if (previousTop !== null && rect.top !== previousTop) {
    lastUnwrappedIndices.push(i - 1);
  }
  previousTop = rect.top;
}

// If the last row isn't wrapped, add its last element
if (lastUnwrappedIndices.length === 0 || lastUnwrappedIndices[lastUnwrappedIndices.length - 1] !== elements.length - 1) {
  lastUnwrappedIndices.push(elements.length - 1);
}

// Apply a class or style to each last element that hasn't wrapped
lastUnwrappedIndices.forEach(index => {
  elements[index].classList.add('last-not-wrapped');
});
```

Comment: If this is all supposed to be left-aligned - then move the border to the other side, and hide the border that will show at the start of a line, by moving `.name-container` to the left by the border width (or border plus padding), and give `#content` `overflow:hidden` to cut that excess off.